# How to get all Instagram post comments via the API instagram?

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I am making an Android-based application that utilizes Instagram API to retrieve comment data from Instagram, where I need all the comments on the post, but after I tried it with a request 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media_id}/comments?access_token={access_token}
I didn't get pagination and only returned the latest 150 comments?

I hope to get all post comments even though the number of comments is more than 150 comments

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've found in the [Instagram API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) about pagination:

[image]

So i think you just need to check in the JSON answer you get, if you can find a `pagination` tag and the `next_url` tag and just call it to get the next results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MatPag, Pagination is for taking Instagram posts but not available when I try to retrieve comment data in one of my post instagram and I try with Instagram API
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN found on Instagram documentation https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/ but I did not find pagination, I only got the latest 150 comments. is there something wrong with the request or the uri that I use?

Comment: Have you tried using the `count` parameter in the request? (for example trying with 200)

Comment: Yes I have tried using the `count` parameter but the results are the same.

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is to contact them and ask if the API is limited in some way which are not described in the documentation